# Simplest wget example Scientific Linux

Tags: linux, command-line, wget, scientific-linux

I'm on Sci Linux and know nothing about commands.

How can I use the `wget` command? Can someone provide a simple example where it actually downloads something?

How do you specify where the download is saved?

Comment: http://linux.about.com/od/commands/a/Example-Uses-Of-The-Command-Wget.htm

Comment: I general, to find out how a command works in *nix, use `man command`. For example, `man wget`.

Comment: You may need to install `wget` first. Check whether it is installed by typing `wget` on the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, `wget` will save to the current directory. To specify a directory, you can:

- use the `-O` parameter to specify a path/file name (e.g. `wget http://foo.bar/file -O outfile` downloads and saves to `outfile`).
- use the `-P` parameter to specify a directory (e.g. `wget http://foo.bar/file -C /tmp` saves to `file` in `/tmp`).

Answer (score 1):

For get a single file:

```
wget <URL>
```

A more complex example, for mirror an entire site (tipical in scientific sites) is:

```
wget -r --convert-links --no-parent -p <URL>
```

In these examples, download is saved in the current directory.